# Undefined method 'map' for ___ when using grouped_collection_select and simpleform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm working on a summer camp registration app.  There are five sessions a day, and each session has a number of classes that a camper can pick from, based on their grade.

Trying to follow the railscast episode on [Dynamic Select Menus](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?view=asciicast), when a camper selects their grade, I want the selection of classes available per session to be filtered by the grade.  (Ie, they pick 2nd grade.. all but the 2nd grade class options are filtered out.)

My first step was to get the grouped_collection_select working.  However, when I load the page I get the following error.

```
undefined method `map' for #<Grade:0x007f93810f6600>
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate it!

grade.rb

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :classes
end
```

class.rb

```
class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :fall_grade_id, :session_ids

  validates_presence_of :fall_grade_id, :session_ids

  belongs_to :grade

  has_many :session_class_relationships
  has_many :sessions, :through => :session_class_relationships
end
```

registration.rb

```
class Registration < AcriveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :fall_grade_id, :session_1_class_id

end
```

registrations/new.html.haml

```
...

= simple_form_for(@registration, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|
    = f.input :fall_grade_id, :collection => 1..6, :prompt => 'Select..', :label => 'Grade'
    = f.input :session_1_class_id, collection: @session_1_classes, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :grade

...
```

Comment: How do you set `@session_1_classes` variable?

Comment: The error should have a filename and line number listed next to it.  What's the line that it's referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@session_1_classes` variable seems to be `Grade` instance instead of `Class` relation. You probably need to do something like this:

```
@session_1_classes = (code_to_find_grade_instance).classes
```

in your controller.